# Is ERROR #98124 WEBPACK the cause of my inability to deploy?

Tags: webpack, cloudflare

I'm trying to deploy to CloudFlare Pages.
The Comment exists in my posts folder.

This is gatsby site

> node v14.18.1 
> gatsby v4.4.0 
> yarn 1.22.17

```
11:42:38.721    <w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Skipped not serializable cache item 'mini-css-extract-plugin /opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[0].use[1]!/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[0].use[2]!/opt/buildhome/repo/src/components/RightSideRssFeedList.module.css|0|Compilation/modules|/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[0].use[1]!/opt/buildhome/repo/node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[10].oneOf[0].use[2]!/opt/buildhome/repo/src/components/RightSideRssFeedList.module.css': No serializer registered for Warning
11:42:38.721    <w> while serializing webpack/lib/cache/PackFileCacheStrategy.PackContentItems -> webpack/lib/NormalModule -> Array { 1 items } -> webpack/lib/ModuleWarning -> Warning
11:42:39.200    [2K[1A[2K[Gfailed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 19.964s
11:42:39.200    
11:42:39.223    [2K[1A[2K[G
11:42:39.223     ERROR #98124  WEBPACK
11:42:39.223    
11:42:39.223    Generating JavaScript bundles failed
11:42:39.223    
11:42:39.223    Can't resolve '../Pages/posts/Comment' in '/opt/buildhome/repo/src/components'
11:42:39.223    
11:42:39.223    If you're trying to use a package make sure that '../Pages/posts/Comment' is
11:42:39.223    installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is
11:42:39.223    correct.
11:42:39.223    
11:42:39.223    File: src/components/PostContent.js:1:184
11:42:39.223    
11:42:39.223    
11:42:39.520    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
```